# Asp.Net(C#) inline coding Eval if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Hi all;**

**How to make inline eval if control ?**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# if(Eval("Bla Bla Bla").ToString().Length <= 15){Eval("Bla Bla Bla")}else{Eval("Bla Bla Bla").ToString().Substring(0,15)}%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the tertiary expression '?':

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Bla Bla Bla").ToString().Length <= 15 ? Eval("Bla Bla Bla") : Eval("Bla Bla Bla").ToString().Substring(0,15) %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: `<pedant>` It's "ternary" (having three parts) `</pedant>` rather than "tertiary" (third in order) ;), or as Eric Lippert points out, just go with " The Conditional Operator": http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/18/whats-the-difference-between-ternary-and-tertiary.aspx

Comment: I could edit my post and correct it but than your comment wouldn't make sense any longer so I'll leave my post intact for all the world to see :)

Comment: edit away, I can always delete my comment, or look like a fool ;)

Comment: @edosoft, what if i use html code in this ? for example: <%#Eval("IsPopUp") ? %> <a href="url" onclick="function();">label</a> <% :  %><a href="url" onclick="function2();">label2</a>